# What is better : sum of prediction or prediction of sum?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

Let's say that I have an input `X = Q + W + Z` and an output `Y`.
Is it better to find a unique predictor using `(X,Y)` or to find 3 predictors using  `(Q,Y), (W,Y), (Z,Y)` and then do the mean of the prediction for these 3 predictors ?
I am looking for some theorical reasons to explane if the 2 procedures are equivalent or if one is better than the other.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These procedures are *not* equivalent, and the first method is generally considered better, at least in the linear case.

Consider, e.g. the situation (in your notation) where one has `(X = Q + W + Z, Y)`, that is, `Y` as a function of `X`. We may rewrite our estimate as (again, assuming linearity),

$$\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta} = Q\hat{\beta_1} + W\hat{\beta_2} + Z\hat{\beta_3}$$

Here, the parameters $\beta_i$ are estimated simultaneously and under some general conditions optimally weighted - informally, all relevant information is used in these estimates. When you instead run the three partial regressions, you are requiring,

$$\hat{Y_q} = Q\hat{\beta_q},~\hat{Y_w} = W\hat{\beta_w},~\hat{Y_z} = Z\hat{\beta_z}$$

And finally, $\hat{Y} = \frac{1}{3} \left[ \hat{Y_q} + \hat{Y_w} + \hat{Y_z} \right]$. Here the weights need *not* be optimal: why would the mean be the 'best' linear combination of these estimates?

Generally, these results will then not be equivalent (*i.a.* because the second specification will, by definition, suffer from omitted variable bias), and the first method should be preferred to the second.